# SQL Server Extended Events to Capture Objects access by a User

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, audit, extended-events

I am in for a requirement where I need to use EE to capture the Objects Accessed by a particular SQL User.

I want to avoid the action `sqlserver.sql_text`, if I use this, I will need to manually scan though the data which may be prone to missing some data or incorrect results.

Is there an alternative to using `sqlserver.sql_text`

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on EE and instead using SQL AUDIT now.

```
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15
```